# How to load data dynamically from firebase database on scrolling using Js for web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

When I refresh page, I am loading 10 records from the database after scrolling another 10 records and it should be displayed. But I am getting same 10 records after scrolling. Here is my code for display 10 records:

```
var discontent = displayContent();
function displayContent(){
      var myFirebase = myFirebased.ref().child('content');
      myFirebase.limitToLast(10).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
)};
```

Below is my code for scrolling:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
     displayContent();  
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/10/queries-part-1-common-sql-queries.html#paginate) for how to implement pagination with Firebase. You can also find a full pagination example as a reference to modify your code accordingly.